# How do I append the build.gradle "versionName" to the release build APK file

Tags: android, gradle

In my app level build.gradle file I have the version name, such as

```
versionName "1.03"
```

When I build a signed release .apk, in Android Studio, the output file is named ***app-release.apk*** 
and is stored in the release directory. How can I update the Gradle build so that the output file is named
***my_application_1.03.apk***

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change your apk file name at release build you can do like as follows.

For Example:  ( app/build.gradle )

```
android {
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name.equals("release")) {
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            if (output.outputFile != null && output.outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                def apk_name = "my_application"
                def versionName = defaultConfig.versionName
                //you can also add version code and date if you like
                //def applicationId = defaultConfig.applicationId
                //def versionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode
                //def date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date())
                def newName = "${apk_name}_${versionName}.apk"
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. Just need to use "variant.outputs.all" instead of "each" above.

Comment: this does not work for aab. don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Below code will run on all variants and build types and also give desire results.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "my-application-${variant.versionName}-${variant.name}.apk"
            }
    }
```